# Facebook PHP SDK Migration Guide from 2.1 to 3.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Has anybody migrated from  2.1 to 3.0. Is there a Migration Guide available for 2.1 to 3.0

What are the things to take care of while migrating.

Also is OpenGraph support present in 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Migration is pretty simple, there was only a few changes to made with regards to access_tokens and getting users.  Took me about a week to fully migrate.

Comment: i deleted what i had and started from scratch with my migration.  the only change that stood out was getting users
$user = $facebook->getUser();